# Возможно ли в TListBox изменить цвет части строки, а не всей строки в целом?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Возможно ли в TListBox изменить цвет части строки, а не всей строки в целом?

Answer (score 1):

Да, вам следует переопределить отрисовку итемов в методе: OnDrawItem(). И вы там можете рисовать все что угодно.

Вот пример: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/OnDrawItem_(Delphi)